# Changing the values on the y axis

Tags: pgfplots

I need the values on the y axis to be 96 instead of 0.96. Meaning, how dow I multiply those y axis values times 2?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}         % multilenguaje

% grid style

\pgfdeclareplotmark{mystar}{
    \node[star,star point ratio=2.25,minimum size=6pt,
    inner sep=0pt,draw=black,solid,fill=red] {};
}

\decimalpoint
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{1,1,0}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{1,0.647058823529412,0}
\begin{document}




    \begin{tikzpicture}



    \begin{axis}[
    axis line style={black},
    scaled x ticks = false,
    legend cell align={left},
    legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)}, anchor=south east, draw=black},
    tick align=outside,
    x grid style={dashed,black!60},
    xlabel={$\lambda$},
    xmajorticks=true,
    xmin=-0.0395, xmax=1.0495,
    xtick style={color=black},
    y grid style={dashed,black!60},
    ylabel={RMSE},
    ymajorticks=true,
    ymin=0.846942213907375, ymax=0.970121133137966,
    ytick style={black},
    xtick align=inside,
    ytick align=inside,
    grid = none,
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=4
    },
    ]
    \addplot [mark =,line width=0.7pt,blue, mark size=2pt]
    table {
0.01 0.8822
0.03 0.8615
0.05 0.854
0.07 0.8597
0.2 0.9155
0.5 0.9344
1 0.9639
};
\addlegendentry{20 f}
\addplot [line width=0.7pt ,black]
table {%
0.01 0.898481256113781
0.03 0.865873246257198
0.05 0.853726601717427
0.07 0.857932550788363
0.2 0.915144334833605
0.5 0.934927092350177
1 0.964522091354758
};
\addlegendentry{30 f}
\addplot [line width=0.7pt, red]
table {%
0.01 0.922581329120646
0.03 0.872177303638855
0.05 0.853365286503622
0.07 0.856359118109799
0.2 0.914724879701767
0.5 0.93512077918702
1 0.964292857206321
};
\addlegendentry{50 f}
\addplot [line width=0.7pt, yellow]
table {%
0.01 0.950247302117098
0.03 0.875862014017094
0.05 0.852945808571336
0.07 0.854889118499624
0.2 0.914000991451563
0.5 0.935209713188576
1 0.963770499326312
};
\addlegendentry{100 f}
\addplot [line width=0.7pt, orange]
table {%
0.01 0.951706952935797
0.03 0.873982593809665
0.05 0.852541255690584
0.07 0.854396792085605
0.2 0.913496001521785
0.5 0.934766529974339
1 0.963747053113756
};
\addlegendentry{150 f}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the `precision` argument to `0` and add the argument `yticklabel = {\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}` to your `axis` environment to multiply the values by 100 and display them:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}         % multilenguaje

% grid style

\pgfdeclareplotmark{mystar}{
    \node[star,star point ratio=2.25,minimum size=6pt,
    inner sep=0pt,draw=black,solid,fill=red] {};
}

\decimalpoint
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{1,1,0}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{1,0.647058823529412,0}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
        axis line style={black},
        scaled x ticks = false,
        legend cell align={left},
        legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)}, anchor=south east, draw=black},
        tick align=outside,
        x grid style={dashed,black!60},
        xlabel={$\lambda$},
        xmajorticks=true,
        xmin=-0.0395, xmax=1.0495,
        xtick style={color=black},
        y grid style={dashed,black!60},
        ylabel={RMSE},
        ymajorticks=true,
        ymin=0.846942213907375, ymax=0.970121133137966,
        ytick style={black},
        xtick align=inside,
        ytick align=inside,
        grid = none,
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=0
        },
        yticklabel = {\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
    ]

        \addplot [mark =,line width=0.7pt,blue, mark size=2pt]
        table {
            0.01 0.8822
            0.03 0.8615
            0.05 0.854
            0.07 0.8597
            0.2 0.9155
            0.5 0.9344
            1 0.9639
        };
        \addlegendentry{20 f}
        \addplot [line width=0.7pt ,black]
        table {%
            0.01 0.898481256113781
            0.03 0.865873246257198
            0.05 0.853726601717427
            0.07 0.857932550788363
            0.2 0.915144334833605
            0.5 0.934927092350177
            1 0.964522091354758
        };
        \addlegendentry{30 f}
        \addplot [line width=0.7pt, red]
        table {%
            0.01 0.922581329120646
            0.03 0.872177303638855
            0.05 0.853365286503622
            0.07 0.856359118109799
            0.2 0.914724879701767
            0.5 0.93512077918702
            1 0.964292857206321
        };
        \addlegendentry{50 f}
        \addplot [line width=0.7pt, yellow]
        table {%
            0.01 0.950247302117098
            0.03 0.875862014017094
            0.05 0.852945808571336
            0.07 0.854889118499624
            0.2 0.914000991451563
            0.5 0.935209713188576
            1 0.963770499326312
        };
        \addlegendentry{100 f}
        \addplot [line width=0.7pt, orange]
        table {%
            0.01 0.951706952935797
            0.03 0.873982593809665
            0.05 0.852541255690584
            0.07 0.854396792085605
            0.2 0.913496001521785
            0.5 0.934766529974339
            1 0.963747053113756
        };
        \addlegendentry{150 f}

        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just change the values accordingly (?)

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}         % multilenguaje

% grid style

\pgfdeclareplotmark{mystar}{
\node[star,star point ratio=2.25,minimum size=6pt,
inner sep=0pt,draw=black,solid,fill=red] {};
}

\decimalpoint
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{1,1,0}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{1,0.647058823529412,0}
\begin{document}




    \begin{tikzpicture}



        \begin{axis}[
        axis line style={black},
        scaled x ticks = false,
        legend cell align={left},
        legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)}, anchor=south east, draw=black},
        tick align=outside,
        x grid style={dashed,black!60},
        xlabel={$\lambda$},
        xmajorticks=true,
        xmin=-0.0395, xmax=1.0495,
        xtick style={color=black},
        y grid style={dashed,black!60},
        ylabel={RMSE},
        ymajorticks=true,
        ymin=84.6942213907375, ymax=97.0121133137966,
        ytick style={black},
        xtick align=inside,
        ytick align=inside,
        grid = none,
        y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=4
        },
        ]
            \addplot [mark =,line width=0.7pt,blue, mark size=2pt]
            table {
            0.01 88.22
            0.03 86.15
            0.05 85.4
            0.07 85.97
            0.2 91.55
            0.5 93.44
            1.0 96.39
            };
            \addlegendentry{20 f}
            \addplot [line width=0.7pt ,black]
            table {%
            0.01 89.8481256113781
            0.03 86.5873246257198
            0.05 85.3726601717427
            0.07 85.7932550788363
            0.2 91.5144334833605
            0.5 93.4927092350177
            1.0 96.4522091354758
            };
            \addlegendentry{30 f}
            \addplot [line width=0.7pt, red]
            table {%
            0.01 92.2581329120646
            0.03 87.2177303638855
            0.05 85.3365286503622
            0.07 85.6359118109799
            0.2 91.4724879701767
            0.5 93.512077918702
            1.0 96.4292857206321
            };
            \addlegendentry{50 f}
            \addplot [line width=0.7pt, yellow]
            table {%
            0.01 95.0247302117098
            0.03 87.5862014017094
            0.05 85.2945808571336
            0.07 85.4889118499624
            0.2 91.4000991451563
            0.5 93.5209713188576
            1.0 96.3770499326312
            };
            \addlegendentry{100 f}
            \addplot [line width=0.7pt, orange]
            table {%
            0.01 95.1706952935797
            0.03 87.3982593809665
            0.05 85.2541255690584
            0.07 85.4396792085605
            0.2 91.3496001521785
            0.5 93.4766529974339
            1.0 96.3747053113756
            };
            \addlegendentry{150 f}
        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This yields you this graph:

[image: Example]

If you don't want the trailing .0000 just change the precision to 0.
And if you don't want to change the values in your `\addplot` see the other provided answer :)